# Making a fake HTTP response in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, httpresponse

As a beginner, I am trying to make a fake HTTP response. The way that comes to my mind is making an object of the class `requests.models.Response()` and then setting its attributes:

```py
def getFakeHTTPResponse(statusCode, text):
        response = requests.models.Response()
        response.status_code = statusCode
        response.text = text
        return response
```

The function above seems should work. But I get the error: `"AttributeError: can't set attribute."` That makes me wonder because it is possible to get the text attribute of an HTTP response but it is not possible to set it. Moreover, this works totally fine for the `status_code` attribute but I get an error for the text attribute.
What do you suggest to make a fake response using this class `requests.models.Response()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `.text` and `.content` methods are implemented using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), so you can read it, but not write. You need to set `._content` (used by `.content`) and `.encoding` (used by `.text`), that is

```
import requests
r = requests.models.Response()
r.status_code = 200
r._content = "sometext".encode("utf-8")
r.encoding = "utf-8"
print(r.text)
```

output

```
sometext
```